# Bash - killall -r does not match

Tags: regex, bash, process, kill-process

I have many processes with similar names, like "proc_1asd, proc_2wqe, proc_3zxc"

I need to send a non-brutal interruption signal to them all, `pkill -f` would work, but it's not installed.

I'm trying to use `killall -r proc_*`, but I get this error

> proc_*: no process found

I have the impression I'm doing something extremely stupid, but I don't know what.

Here's an image (actual name of the processes is jnode_something)

[image: Task manager screenshot]

`pgrep -lf 'proc_.*'` returns

```
15070 jnode_0 -cp lib/xstream-1.4.7.jar:build/classes sandbox.GridNode Configs/0_config.txt Logs
15071 jnode_1 -cp lib/xstream-1.4.7.jar:build/classes sandbox.GridNode Configs/1_config.txt Logs
15072 jnode_2 -cp lib/xstream-1.4.7.jar:build/classes sandbox.GridNode Configs/2_config.txt Logs
15073 jnode_3 -cp lib/xstream-1.4.7.jar:build/classes sandbox.GridNode Configs/3_config.txt Logs
15074 jnode_4 -cp lib/xstream-1.4.7.jar:build/classes sandbox.GridNode Configs/4_config.txt Logs
```

Comment: works fine for me. What version of killall and what OS ?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and killall (PSmisc) 22.15. But it's not working in Ubuntu. I need this to work on another Unix later, though. Still, if it does not work on Ubuntu, I guess I have no chance.

Comment: Strangely, it works for firefox with `killall -r firef*`, but not for those processes. They are there though, I can see them in the Task Manager. And `pkill -f proc_*` works on Ubuntu, but I can't use it in the other Unix.

Comment: Never used the `-r` feature but since it's supposed to be a regular expression you need to use `.*` instead of the simple `*` wildcard so your invocation should look like `killall -r proc_.*`.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth tried that, but it's not working either

Comment: Can you provide the output of `pgrep -l 'proc_.*'`? You might also want to try `pkill` instead of `killall` doing `pkill 'proc_.*'` (`killall` is part of `psmisc` whereas `pgrep`/`pkill` come with `procps`).

Comment: `pgrep -l 'proc_.*' > outp.txt` produces an empty file, yet `pkill -f jnode_.*` kills the processes. I added a screenshot of the Task manager.

Comment: What about `pgrep -lf 'proc_.*'`?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth OK, that actually returns something. See the answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like overkill, but if you can get the PIDs from pgrep, just use them as arguments to kill. Something like:

```
pgrep -lf 'proc_.*' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -f
```

Comment: where `-f` is actually the number of the signal `-2` should be fine for non-brutal termination.

Comment: This *is* overkill, just do `pgrep -f 'proc_.*' | xargs kill` ;-)

Comment: Ubuntu14LTS use pgrep -f 'proc_.*' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill